# what is the correct way of uploading image to a specific url when i am downloading a image from a another url?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios4, nsurlconnection

I am successfully completed 75% of my task.The main problem is image uploading.
Connection is established.but encoding data cannot be uploaded.here i am writing my code like this way

```
UIImage *naveen = [UIImage  imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL  

URLWithString:@"http://www.watblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/b.jpg"]]];

myimages.image=naveen;
```

by using the above code i load the image very successfully.

the above code i write in did load method.

After that i take an IBAction in that i write below code

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myimages.image, 90);

NSString *encodedImage = [Base64 encode:imageData];

NSLog(@"my encoded image is 6666%@",encodedImage);
```

**//here i am getting encoded image data**

it is also successful

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://192.168.1.105:9966/PC/store";


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"--------------------------

-14737809831466499882746641449"];

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; 

boundary=%@",boundary];


[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

 NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"rn--%@rn",boundary] 

dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


  [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; 

name=\"encodedImage\"; filename=\"http://www.watblog.com/wp-

content/uploads/2011/11/b.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-streamrnrn"] 

dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"rn--%@--rn",boundary] 

dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil 

error:nil];

NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData 

encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(returnString);

}
```

**whenever i execute the above code the return string is**

> final[3077:f803]
>
> html>Apache Tomcat/6.0.35 - Error
>   report
>
> family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;}
>   H2
>
> {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;}
>
> H3
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-
>
> size:14px;} BODY
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;}
>   B
>
> {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-
>
> family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A
>   {color :
>
> black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}-->
>
> ## HTTP Status
>
> 404 - /PC/store
>
> **type**
>   Status report
>
> **message** /PC/store
>
> **description** The
>   requested resource
>
> (/PC/store) is not available.
>
> #### Apache
>
> Tomcat/6.0.35

please anybody help me how to pass my encoded data

I am beginner to iPhone programming

Answer (score 0):

That seems more like a problem with backend server.
Try to upload file with any other method - i.e. from simple HTML form.

This may not be a clue, but why you're using full URL for a filename?

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"encodedImage\"; filename=\"http://www.watblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/b.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```